# Comma before "and" meaning

Tags: commas

"Person A shall not be interviewed unless he/she and person B is present, and have been advised of and understand the consequences."

In the above sentence, what does the comma placement mean?

If both parties understand and accept the consequences but then person B chooses not to be present for the interview, is it invalidated?

Comment: It means that whoever wrote it was wearing Oxfords.

Comment: It first means, the writer didn't think about what he meant. "Person A shall not be interviewed unless he/she… (anything) is present…" makes nonsense of anything that follows…

Answer (score 1):

The comma is there for you to understand there are two **separate** conditions to fulfill for A to be interviewed. Not that A needs B to be both 'present and advised'.

The two conditions are:

1. both person A and B must be present.
2. The second condition is that person A has been advised.

As I understand it, and if there are no further condition saying the contrary, yes. Person A shall not be interviewed if person B is not present.